# Directional/spotlight light in threejs with helper

Tags: javascript, three.js

i m following this guide for the light [Light in Threejs](https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-lights.html)
and i already add some light in my scene.

Now i m try to add a light on the character of my game, but still dont work. 
i use the same code of the guide changing just the position.set

```
 const color = 0xFFFFFF;
 const intensity = 1;

 const light2 = new THREE.SpotLight(color, intensity,0,Math.PI/3);
 light2.position.set(100,-5000,1000);

 light2.target = lightTarget;
 light2.castShadow = true;
 const helper2 = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(light2);
```

and after i add in this way to my character

```
       self.flame.add( helper2 );
       self.flame.add(lightTarget);
       self.flame.add(light2);
```

I added a helper too, but if I use just the helper in the scene , so if comment

```
  self.flame.add(light2)
```

I see the position of the light in perfect way, when add the light the helper disappear (in other light don't happened) and the light go as her want.

Someone can help me?

Comment: Any chances to demonstrate the issue with a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)?

Answer (score 1):

The helpers have to be parented to the scene (or at least the SpotLightHelper does). You may or may not want to parent the target to the scene.

You also need to call `helper.update` for each helper

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE, dat */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 45;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 100;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 10, 20);

  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, canvas);
  controls.target.set(0, 5, 0);
  controls.update();

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('black');

  {
    const planeSize = 40;

    const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    const texture = loader.load('https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/checker.png');
    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter;
    const repeats = planeSize / 2;
    texture.repeat.set(repeats, repeats);

    const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeSize, planeSize);
    const planeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      map: texture,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    });
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, planeMat);
    mesh.rotation.x = Math.PI * -.5;
    scene.add(mesh);
  }
  const cubes = [];
  let parent = scene;
  {
    const cubeSize = 1;
    const cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
    const cubeMat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
     color: '#8AC',
     emissive: '#333',
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
      const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
      mesh.position.set(1, 0, 0);
      parent.add(mesh);
      cubes.push(mesh);
      parent = mesh;
    }
  }
  cubes[0].position.set(-3, 7, 0);
  
  const color = 0xFFFFFF;
  const intensity = 1;
  const light = new THREE.SpotLight(color, intensity);
  light.position.set(0, 0, 0);
  light.target.position.set(0, -1, 0);
  parent.add(light);
  parent.add(light.target);
  //scene.add(light.target);

  const helper = new THREE.SpotLightHelper(light);
  scene.add(helper);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    
    for (const cube of cubes) {
      cube.rotation.z = Math.sin(time) * .4;
    }
    light.angle = THREE.Math.lerp(
       THREE.Math.degToRad(20), 
       THREE.Math.degToRad(80),
       Math.sin(time * 0.77) * 0.5 + 0.5);
    
    helper.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for answear Gman. Maybe is this the problem, because i use the light in a function and add this light at part of scene (in one object). I already use light and add in other element with scene.add(light) and work perfect, but in this case i need to add a light just at one element (specify in the own function). Because i already create a man, and now I want add a sort of torch in him hand. With pointlight no problem, but with directional or spotlight starting this problem